# iphone - UITableview - headerview doesn't load objectkeys

Tags: iphone, xcode, header, plist, tableview

I have a table view, with an added headerview created in IB to display some text above the table (couldn't post the screenshot- http://i51.tinypic.com/2przbl5.jpg). I would like to load the text above the table based on my plist and I am using objectforkey to load the text. However when I connect the outlets in IB the text disappears. This worked in a standard UIview so I'm not sure what I'm missing in the table view. I'm new to coding so perhaps there a better way to do this or what am i doing wrong? thanks.

```
.h file _________________________________________________


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TourOverviewController : UITableViewController {

 NSArray *points;
 NSDictionary *tour;
 IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
 IBOutlet UITextView *pointsTextView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *points;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *tour;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *pointsTextView;


@end

.m file______________________________________________________

    #import "TourOverviewController.h"
#import "LoadingNames.h"

@implementation TourOverviewController
@synthesize points, tour, nameTextField, pointsTextView, 

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];

 nameTextField.text = [tour objectForKey:NAME_KEY];
 pointsTextView.text = [tour objectForKey:DIRECTIONS_KEY];  
}


- (void)viewDidLoad { 
 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Toy Story",
                      @"A Bug's Life", @"Toy Story 2", @"Monsters, Inc.", 
                      @"Finding Nemo", @"The Incredibles", @"Cars", 
                      @"Ratatouille", @"WALL-E", nil];
    self.points = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [points count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *rowString = [points objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = rowString;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [rowString release];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure I understand your question but you could create 2 plists, points and tour and then fill your Mutable array and dictionary with the contents of the plist.

EDIT**************************************************

I missed this before, but maybe it as simple as adding a @" " e.g.

```
[tour objectForKey:@"NAME_KEY"];
```

---

You should make your array and dictionary mutable if you want to change the data within them for whatever reason.

Here is so code to get the plist and fill your array or dictionary(be sure to set the plists to the appropriate type when you fill them)

Put this in your viewDidLoad method

```
NSString *pointsList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
  pathForResource:@"points" ofType:@"plist"];
  points = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: pointsList];

NSString *tourList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
  pathForResource:@"tour" ofType:@"plist"];
  tour = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: tourList];
```

Then you have your array and dictionary filled with the contents of the plist.

Hope this helps, maybe I misunderstood want you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I had something similar in my rootcontoller. When I add this it runs and I get the same result. When I take the same items out of the tableheader and just in a UIview everything links up fine... so i'm thinking its related to something in the table header i'm missing.

Comment: This should solve your issue. :) http://www.purplehazeapps.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=84:headerfooterinuitableview&catid=37:myblog&Itemid=171

Comment: Thanks for all the help you guys!! I just figured it out, when I pushed the page from my rootcontroller i had inadvertently deleted the line with the plist file. yeah its finally working =)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are using a UITableViewController, text like the one you are trying to display has to go in the table header.
Here is how you can add a label to a table header:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100)];
UILabel *header = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 50)];
[header setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[header setText:@"Some Text"];
[headerView addSubview:header];

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
```

Comment: I tried adding this and it replaces the headerview I created in IB. I would like to use the header in IB, but I can't get the connected outlets to load.

Comment: Have you connected the IBOutlets in the code to the ones in the nib file through Interface Builder?